# How can I fill an empty dataframe with zero in pandas? Fillna not working

Tags: python, pandas

A dataframe is being created by a process and sometimes the process returns an empty dataframe with no values at all. In that case I want the dataframe to be filled with zeroes for all the columns. I've tried `output_df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)` but it doesn't work. The dataframe just remains empty.

Comment: can you provide an example for clarity?

Answer (score 1):

To replace all values with 0, you can use:

```
df.loc[:] = 0
```

If you really have no rows and want to add one:

```
df.loc[0] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If has empty DataFrame only with columns names possible solution for add `0` is use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by some list for new indices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])

df = df.reindex([0, 1, 2], fill_value=0)
print (df)
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  0
2  0  0
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df = df.reindex(index=[0, 1, 2], columns=list('ab'), fill_value=0)
print (df)
     a    b
0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0
```